# SQL query with group by rollup clause and formats

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My SQL query and output is as follows:

```
Select 
    c.caseName, ci.caseBy, lk.desc, c.prepared 
from 
    cases c 
left outer join  
    case_info ci on c.tin = ci.tin
left outer join 
    lk_zone lk on lk.id = c.id 
where 
    c.delete_dt is not null;
```

Output:

```
caseName    caseBy  zone    Prepared
------------------------------------
ABC         10      Above   N 
BCD         11      Above   Y             
ABC         10      In      N
BCD         11      Below   N            
CEF         12      Above   Y
CEF         12      In      N 
CEF         12      Below   N
BCD         11      In      Y
CEF         13      Above   N
CEF         13      In      Y
CEF         13      Below   N
```

Expected output:

```
CaseName    aseBy  zone      Cases    Prepped   %Comp
-------------------------------------------------------
ABC          10     Above       1       0          0%
ABC          10     In          1       0          0%
ABC          10     Below                                                                                                
BCD          11     Above       1       1        100%
BCD          11     In          1       1        100%
BCD          11     Below       1       0          0%
CEF          12     Above       1       1        100%
CEF          12     In          1       0          0%
CEF          12     Below       1       0          0%
CEF          13     Above       1       0          0%
CEF          13     In          1       1        100%
CEF          13     Below       1       0          0%

Total                          11       4         36.36%
```

For this I changed the query as follows:

```
Select 
    c.caseName, ci.caseBy, lk.desc Zone, 
    sum(nvl2(PREPARED, 1, 0)) as cases, 
    sum(decode(PREPARED, 'Y', 1, 0)) as prepped,
    round(avg(CASE WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END), 2)||'%' as comp
from 
    cases c 
left outer join 
    case_info ci on c.tin = ci.tin
left outer join 
    lk_zone lk on lk.id = c.id 
where
    c.delete_dt is not null
group by 
    rollup(caseName, caseBy, lk.descr);
```

This does not returned the expected result as outlined above, `In` and `Below` for all the combinations of caseName, CaseBy. Say for example caseName ABC and caseBy 10 doesn't have Below record. In that case I should have the row displayed with 0 or empty values. Also I would want the totals as defined.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the data.  You are not clear on what the data looks like, so my best guess is:

```
select c.caseName, ci.caseBy, lk.desc, c.prepared 
from cases c cross join
     lk_zone lk left join 
     case_info ci
     on c.tin = ci.tin and 
       lk.id = c.id 
where c.delete_dt is not null;
```

You can then modify this for the additional columns and rows.